# Intellij not recognizing Dropwizard version dependency

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, dropwizard

I've started to create a java project using the dropwizard framework and maven. My `pom.xml` file looks like

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.dexcane</groupId>
    <artifactId>dexcane-backend</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <dropwizard.version>2.1.4-SNAPSHOT</dropwizard.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.dropwizard.archetypes/dropwizard-archetypes -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

I'm following the dropwizard [tutorial](https://www.dropwizard.io/en/latest/getting-started.html). When I hover over the "2.1.4-SNAPSHOT"  dependency Intellij says "Dependency 'io.dropwizard:dropwizard-core:2.1.4-SNAPSHOT' not found ". Does anyone know what's wrong with the import? The tutorial says the current version of dropwizard is `2.1.4-SNAPSHOT`.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't add it with the type of pom as its packaging is jar.